# Pointer confusion in C programming language

Tags: c, pointers

Hello guys and a happy new year!

I have difficulty understanding pointers in C language. 
As far as I learned a pointer is a special variable that stores addresses of regular variables.

Ι am posting two samples of code which are equivalent. In the first I typed into scanf the `&d1.am`.

In the second sample if I change the `&d1.am` to `ptd1.am` it pops up a **compile error** and I cannot understand why.

```
struct student{
    int am;
    char stname[20];
    char stsurname[20];
};

int main(){

struct student d1;
printf("1st student\n");
printf("Enter am\n");
scanf("%d", &d1.am)
```

Second equivalent sample:

```
struct student{
    int am;
    char stname[20];
    char stsurname[20];
};

int main(){

struct student d1;
struct student *ptd1;
ptd1=&d1;
printf("1st student\n");
printf("Enter am\n");
scanf("%d", &(*ptd1).am);
```

I know the correct is to type `&(*ptd1).am` instead but I can't figure why. How `&(*ptd1).am` is equal to `&d1.am` and `ptd1.am` is not? I typed clearly that `ptd1=&d1`!

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I would use scanf("%d", &(ptd1->am));

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.` operator has higher precedence than unary `&`. `&d1.am` is equivalent to `&(d1.am)` while `ptd1.am` is equivalent to `(&d1).am`, that said `&d1.am` != `(&d1).am`.

Comment: I like the explaination on how `&d1.am` and `(&d1).am` differ.

Comment: Thanks mate, nice explanation!!

Comment: @Skemelio; Glad to know that it helped you.

Comment: @haccks Can I ask you one more thing? Why  &(*ptd1).am and not just  &(ptd1).am? Sorry friend, I am trying to understand before I ask but I cannot! Thanks in advance

Comment: @Skemelio Have a look at [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) for more info

Comment: Lets dissect `&(*ptd1).am` -- starting in the parens `*ptd1` says "dereference ptd1", that is, "what does ptd1 point at" (`d1` in this case).  Then the `.` is the next highest precedence operator, so now we have "the value in the "am" field of "d1".  But scanf for an int needs the address of the int, so that's why that '&' is there.  By the way, most C programmers will use the `->` operator as a shortcut, because `ptd1->am == (*ptd1).am` -- which means you end up with the much prettier `&ptd1->am`

Comment: @Skemelio; In this case `ptd1` is equivalent to  `&d1`. So, `&(ptd1).am` is equivalent to `&(&d1).am`, which is not what you wanted.

Comment: @JohnHascall Thank you sir!

Answer (score 3):

The structure access operator (`.`) [has higher precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) than the address-of operator (`&`). So `&d1.am` is the address of the `am` member of `d1`, which is an `int*`, which differs from the type of `ptd1` (`struct student *`).

Comment: Thanks for your effort bro!

Answer (score 1):

Has other have said the `.` operator has higher precedence than `&`. So that ptd1.am is equivalent to (&d1).am (see for example the answer from @haccks).

I want to add that **ptd1** is a *pointer to struct* and thus to get a member you should use `->`. The call to scanf should be:

```
scanf("%d", &(ptd1->am));
```

Comment: Actually I am trying to get into this part. God why this thing with pointers is so confusing I just want to be done with it!

Comment: @Skemelio. Don't worry, pointers are not so easy to understand you need time. Take a look at this nice article about how to become a great programmer http://norvig.com/21-days.html

Answer (score 0):

As u have written ptd1=&d1;
that means that *ptd1 will point to d1 .

So if you want to access d1.am you need to write (*ptd1).am .

But here you are passing to scanf and it needs memory address so need to pass with & and so you need to put &(*ptd1).am.

As others have mentioned (.) has higher priority so  (.) will choose it operands first and expression will be equal to
&((*ptd1).am)

Better to use &(ptd1->am)